# Calabash html report ignores errors during Before phase

Tags: android, testing, cucumber, calabash

When running the Calabash tests I get an error during the Before phase but <strike>the report exits with 0 code.</strike>  It says that all the tests were failed because all the steps were skipped but the HTML report is green.

How can I make the report show that there was an error?

**Updated:** The exit code is correct. If it fails it returns a non 0 code. The problem is the html formatter. I'm running it with the following flag:
--format=html --out ./target/calabash-reports.html

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
screenshot_and_raise "Error description"
```

line in side ruby step definitions where you want to raise the error

Eg:

```
Then /^I (?:press|touch) list item number (\d+)$/ do |index|
   index = index.to_i
   screenshot_and_raise "Index should be positive (was: #{index})" if (index<=0)
   touch("tableViewCell index:#{index-1}")
   sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```

Comment: The problem is in the Before phase. I just run raise and it doesn't report as an error. Here the issue I created in the calabash-android repository: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/316

Comment: will you be able to run any other feature files fine on the same PC with same app and get a report?

Comment: the github issue is closed.  this is not a problem with calabash.  it is a problem with cucumber.